# Python. Как поменять IP для запроса в requests?

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Пытался через публичные прокси (requests.get(url, proxy=proxy)) , не работает. Поискал как можно без прокси менять IP, ничего толком не нашёл. Покупать прокси возможности нет. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Без прокси/ВПН никак

Comment: Потому что нельзя его менять. Альтернатива прокси - впн. Можно схитрить и выдать себя за прокси хидером `X-Forwarded-For`, но не более.

Comment: @vitidev - красивая идея! Автору вопроса: а может, Вы хотите чего то другого, чем мы тут думаем? Можно поподробнее написать вопрос? а то сейчас он не очень однозначный...